# Como herdar um form em c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho uma aplicação com o formulário `FormFuncionario`. Desejo herdar todas as características desse formulário para uma segunda classe, chamada `ControlFuncionario`, onde a mesma ficará responsável por realizar diversos eventos, e, inclusive, acessar o banco de dados. Me foi ensinado que não devo deixar a lógica e a parte de banco de dados direto na camada **GUI**, por isso criei outra chamada **BLL** e tentei aplicar o seguinte código :

```
namespace BLL.Pessoal // Camada/Pasta que está localizada a classe
{
    class ControlFuncionario : GUI.FormFuncionario //Aponta erro

    {
    }
}
```

O erro é o seguinte :

> CS0012  C# The type 'Form' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly.

Minha dúvida é como eu herdo esse Form para uma classe "comum" ...

Comment: cria um form vazio primeiro, depois troca o `: Form` por `: GUI.FormFuncionario`

Comment: Se o `FormFuncionario` estiver no Projeto `GUI` e `class ControlFuncionario` estiver em no projeto BLL, vc tem que adicionar referência do GUI em BLL, para ter acesso ao conteúdo.

Comment: Você tem certeza que trazer um form da GUI como referência para a sua BLL? O correto seria o contrário. E na BLL disponibilizar todos os métodos necessários para o funcionamento do form... Agora a sua GUI é um Windows.Form... Amanhã pode ser um MVC, Web.Api e etc... Não faria sentido, não? Inclusive a sua BLL também não deveria acessar diretamente o banco de dados...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como o erro diz, os binários do tipo `Form` não estão referenciados no projeto que contém a classe `ControlFuncionario`.

Adicione a este projeto uma referência ao *assembly* **`System.Windows.Forms`**.